# Event.d not there

Tags: upstart, services, git, etc

Using ubuntu server 14.04.2

I'm trying to get the git daemon on my server it tells me to create an upstart script at /etc/event.d/local-git-daemon. However it seems there is no event.d in /etc. Upstart is installed..

Do i need to manually install eventd or something of the sort? Or can i just put the script in /etc/init?

Comment: what's the output for `ls /etc/* | grep event` ?

Comment: @JoKeR It shows no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer on ubuntuforums:
In 10.04 Upstart jobs are defined in files placed in /etc/init.

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Had to look a bit better it appears :-P